# How to put a tooltip on input when its not valid

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I want to show a tooltip on ma text input when it's not valid

```js
function check() {
  var ok = true;
  regLast = /^[a-zA-Z]{2,20}$/;

  if (!regLast.test(document.getElementById("lastName").value)) {
    ok = false;
  }

  return ok;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="lastName">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Put your last name" name="lastName" />
</div>
```

and I know how to put, a text in a div under, a input by `document.getElementById("wronglastnamediv").innerHTML = "Put valid last name"`

But I don't know how to put a tooltip on these text area when it's not valid..

Comment: use jquery validation plugin instead of writing custom code. here are some examples https://thrilleratplay.github.io/jquery-validation-bootstrap-tooltip/ or https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Yep, I wanted to use it, but my professor said that I can't use things like that, I have to write validation in JS on my own.

Comment: See [Form data validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation) and specifically check out the [HTMLSelectElement.setCustomValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/setCustomValidity) method. This is the proper tool for the job.

Answer (score 2):

You can add tooltip for the input field like this. Use `setAttribute('title', 'some tooltip')` to set the tooltip and `removeAttribute('title')` to remove the tooltip from the input field.

I have added input-event listener to the input field that performs validation of the input value each time you type a character and based on the result of the validation it either adds or removes the tooltip.

If you type just one character and hover over the input field, you should see the tooltip. If you type a second character it disappears (note that you need to move mouse cursor outside of the input field and then back to actually see the tooltip).

```js
function check() {
  var ok = true;
  const regLast = /^[a-zA-Z]{2,20}$/;

  if (!regLast.test(document.getElementById("lastName").value)) {
    ok = false;
  }

  return ok;
}

const inp = document.querySelector('input');
inp.addEventListener('input', event => {
  if (!check(inp.value)) {
    inp.setAttribute('title', 'incorrect value');
  } else {
    inp.removeAttribute('title');
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for ="lastName">Last name:</label>
  <input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "lastName" placeholder = "Put your last name" name = "lastName" />
</div>
```

---

If you need something more sophisticated and more 'visible' then you can use css combined with data attributes. The logic is the same as with the previous code. Based on the result of validation you either add a data attribute to the input field or remove it.

```js
function check() {
  var ok = true;
  const regLast = /^[a-zA-Z]{2,20}$/;

  if (!regLast.test(document.getElementById("lastName").value)) {
    ok = false;
  }

  return ok;
}

const inp = document.querySelector('input');
inp.addEventListener('input', event => {
  if (!check(inp.value)) {
    inp.parentElement.dataset.tip = 'incorrect input value';
  } else {
    delete inp.parentElement.dataset.tip;
  }
});
```

```css
[data-tip] {
 position:relative;

}
[data-tip]:before {
 content:'';
 display:none;
 content:'';
 border-left: 5px solid transparent;
 border-right: 5px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #1a1a1a;
 position:absolute;
 top:30px;
 left:35px;
 z-index:8;
 font-size:0;
 line-height:0;
 width:0;
 height:0;
}
[data-tip]:after {
 display:none;
 content:attr(data-tip);
 position:absolute;
 top:35px;
 left:0px;
 padding:5px 8px;
 background:#1a1a1a;
 color:#fff;
 z-index:9;
 font-size: 0.75em;
 height:18px;
 line-height:18px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 white-space:nowrap;
 word-wrap:normal;
}
[data-tip]:hover:before,
[data-tip]:hover:after {
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group" >
  <label for ="lastName">Last name:</label>
  <input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "lastName" placeholder = "Put your last name" name = "lastName" />
</div>
```

---

To add the tooltip on form submit instead of hover, you can use `submit-event listener` and execute the same code as before but you need to add `event.preventDefault();` as well to prevent the form from submitting if the validation fails (and you need to change the css slightly).

When you click submit button now, you should see the tooltip if the input value is incorrect.

```js
function check() {
  var ok = true;
  const regLast = /^[a-zA-Z]{2,20}$/;

  if (!regLast.test(document.getElementById("lastName").value)) {
    ok = false;
  }

  return ok;
}

const inp = document.querySelector('input');
const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  if (!check(inp.value)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    inp.parentElement.dataset.tip = 'incorrect input value';
  } else {
    delete inp.parentElement.dataset.tip;
  }
});
```

```css
[data-tip] {
 position:relative;

}
[data-tip]:before {
 content:'';
 border-left: 5px solid transparent;
 border-right: 5px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #1a1a1a;
 position:absolute;
 top:30px;
 left:35px;
 z-index:8;
 font-size:0;
 line-height:0;
 width:0;
 height:0;
}
[data-tip]:after {
 content:attr(data-tip);
 position:absolute;
 top:35px;
 left:0px;
 padding:5px 8px;
 background:#1a1a1a;
 color:#fff;
 z-index:9;
 font-size: 0.75em;
 height:18px;
 line-height:18px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 white-space:nowrap;
 word-wrap:normal;
}
[data-tip]:hover:before,
[data-tip]:hover:after {
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group" >
    <label for ="lastName">Last name:</label>
    <input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "lastName" placeholder = "Put your last name" name = "lastName" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: It's doin nothing - it won't submit my form, but any tooltip or text isn't here

Comment: @Dr.Weiss Well it works here in snippet, but try the other example I have posted if it works for you.

Comment: Oh, I see how it works now, but it's possible to do it that when I submit it, its shows? Not on hover?

Comment: @Dr.Weiss Check the third example.

Comment: What should I edit when I have button like that: `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="save()" >Submit</button>`

Comment: @Dr.Weiss I think that that if you replace `<input type="submit" value="submit" />` with the code you have just posted then it should work the same. Validation, as well as tooltip handling is bound to form submit event.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit the below code accordingly, also link the jquery 1.7 or above-

```
<script>
 $('#lastName').on('keyup', function () {

$('.text-error').remove();
var ok=true;
regLast = /^[a-zA-Z]{2,20}$/;
if (!regLast.test(document.getElementById("lastName").value))
{
    ok=false;
    $(this).parent('.form-group').append("<span class='text-error'>Please enter a valida string.</span>");
}
return ok;

});
</script>

//CSS add your own CSS for tooltip style etc
<style type="text/css">
.form-group{
position:relative;
}
.text-error{
position:absolute;
right:0;
top:0px;
background:red;
color:white;
border-radius:5px;
padding:5px 3px;
}
</style>
```

Hopefully the code will work for you.

Pure Javascript

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <title></title>

            <style type="text/css">
            .form-control{
                position:relative;
                width: 100%;
                float: left;
            }
            .text-error{
                position:absolute;
                right:0;
                top:0px;
                background:red;
                color:white;
                border-radius:5px;
                padding:5px 3px;
                display: none;
            }
            .display_block{
                display: block;
            }
            </style>

            </head>
            <body>




            <div class="form-group">
              <label for ="lastName">Last name:</label>
              <input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "lastName" onkeyup="check()" placeholder = "Put your last name" name = "lastName" />
              <span class="text-error" id="error_lastname"></span>
            </div>


            <script type="text/javascript">
            function check () {
                var div = document.getElementById("error_lastname");
                div.setAttribute('class', 'text-error'); 

                var ok=true;
                regLast = /^[a-zA-Z]{2,20}$/;
                if (!regLast.test(document.getElementById("lastName").value))
                {
                    ok=false;

                    div.setAttribute('class', 'text-error display_block'); 
                    div.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid string.";


                    console.log("XXXX");

                }
                return ok;

            }

            </script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: No jQuery were allowed...and the question doesn't have it in its tag list either

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [HTML5 Form Validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation) (If you don't want a custom tooltip).

See the code snippet below:

```html
<form>
    <p>
        <label for="firstName">First name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="Put your first name" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2,20}" required />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="lastName">Last name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Put your last name" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2,20}" required />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" Value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Also you can use `setCustomValidity` function when `oninvalid` event occurs to to change the default message of the required field.

**Example:**

```html
<form>
    <p>
        <label for="firstName">First name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="Put your first name" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2,20}" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid Name')" required />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="lastName">Last name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Put your last name" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2,20}" required />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" Value="Submit" />
</form>
```